# wp_authenticate_username_password not authenticating properly when pass username and password

Tags: users, authentication

I am developing  custom login page and want to login through username and password. To authenticate user, i am using this function wp_authenticate_username_password()

```
$usr_user = wp_authenticate_username_password($user_obj, $username, $password)
print_r($usr_user);
```

But when I enter wrong password, its still giving user object in return. When I enter wrong username and password then only its giving error. On providing correct username and wrong password its returning user object. I think thats not how it meant to work. It should not return user object when passing wrong password Anyone who else have faced this or know about it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code of [`wp_authenticate_username_password()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_authenticate_username_password/), if you're passing a valid WP_User object in the `$user_obj` parameter, it will simply be returned. Only if `$user_obj` is *not* a valid WP_User will the `$username` and `$password` parameters be checked.

If you're trying to ensure a user's username and password are valid, I'd recommend using [`wp_authenticate()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_authenticate/) instead.

Comment: Thanks. It helped me.
When I passed empty user id like this - wp_authenticate_username_password('', $usr_username, $usr_password);  then its working fine.